# Zk jmeter plugin

Tags: jmeter, zk, jmeter-plugins

I want to perform load tests on Zkoss with jmeter. I have installed jmeter and the zk jmeter plugin. then i placed the jar file in jmeter/lib/ext folder as specified in the Zk site http://blog.zkoss.org/2013/08/06/zk-jmeter-plugin/.

Now i am facing a problem. when I place this jar in the respective folder. My jmeter application is getting crashed and showing me an error :
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class or
g.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory. See log file for details.

So please help me out with this.
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jmeter 3.2, then probably it is your case:
http://forum.zkoss.org/question/105222/zk-jmeter-plugin-080jar-not-working-with-jmeter-32/
(use 3.1)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But could you please help me how can i change the version of my jmeter from 3.2 to 3.1 without losing any files from this version of jmeter.

Comment: What files are you afraid to lose ? Just download older version and use it. Test plan very likely will work ok